# Can't connect to new CRM Online Security model with XrmDataContext

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

Microsoft has changed the authentication model for new CRM sites from LiveID to Microsoft Online Services. I set up a new site this week and have it up and running but code I wrote that connects to the site using early bound classes fails to authenticate.

My connection string for an older site using LiveIDs looks like this.

I am trying to connect to the new site that uses Microsoft Online Services for authentication with this connection string

I create an instance of XrmDataContext and it seems to work OK until I actually upll data fromthe site. The error I receive is 
ACS10002: An error occurred while processing the SOAP body. ACS50012: Authentication failed.

I tried all of the authentication types list here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681567 and none seemed to work.

I see a lot of forum posts saying that the discovery service URL has changed so I tried adding that to my connection string.
Discovery URL=https://disco.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc

No luck.

Has anyone written code that connects to the new security model? Did you do anything special?

Thanks in advance,
Bill Wolohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS released a new version of the SDK on 8/17/2012. I had downloaded the latest on 8/16/2012 and that version did not work. Once I downloaded the newer version and recompiled it worked great. I just had bad timing. :-(